# Pass current transaction to DbCommand

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, ef-core-2.1

I'm working on a project using ASP.NET Core 2.1 and EF Core 2.1. Although most of queries and commands use EF, some units needs to call stored procedures directly.

I can't use `FromSql`, because it needs results set based on entity models.

Let's assume we have these methods:

```
public Task CommandOne(DbContext context)
{
    Entity entity = new Entity
    {
        Name = "Name"
    };

    context.DbSet<Entity>().Add(entity);

    return context.SaveChangesAsync();
}

public async Task CommandTwo(DbContext context)
{
    DbCommand command = context.Database.GetDbConnection().CreateCommand();
    command.CommandText = "storedProcName";
    command.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;

    using (var reader = await command.ExecuteReaderAsync().ConfigureAwait(false))
    {
        // read result sets
    }
}
```

If I call both commands in one transaction like this:

```
public async Task UnitOfWork(DbContext dbContext)
{
    using (var transaction = await dbContext.Database.BeginTransactionAsync())
    {
        await CommandOne(dbContext);
        await CommandTwo(dbContext);
    }
}
```

This exception happens:

> BeginExecuteReader requires the command to have a transaction when the
> connection assigned to the command is in a pending local transaction.
> The Transaction property of the command has not been initialized.

I have to mention, it's not as simple as `command.Transaction = ...`. This requires `DbTransaction` which differs from the transaction EF uses.

I've been stuck with this for a month!

Is there any workaround for this?

Thank you so much.

Comment: Where do you mark the transaction as complete `transaction.Complete()`

Comment: @Eldho before scope of transaction closes

Answer (score 22, accepted):

> I have to mention, it's not as simple as `command.Transaction = ....` This requires `DbTransaction` which differs from the transaction EF uses.

Actually it is. All you need is a reference to  **Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational** assembly and add

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage;
```

to get access to [`GetDbTransaction`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.storage.dbcontexttransactionextensions.getdbtransaction?view=efcore-2.1) extension method:

```
command.Transaction = context.Database.CurrentTransaction?.GetDbTransaction();
```