# Microsoft.Data.Entity not found in EntityFrameworkCore.Relational

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I am trying to use GetDbConnection() in the Database object in EntityframeworkCore. After referencing all the components(abstractions, design, proxies, relational and sqlserver ) of EF Core, I do not have access to the GetDbConnection() method. I  guess this is an extension method.

Pls. note that am using EF Core 2.1.4.

My actual task is to execute raw sql with multiple JOIN(s).

Kindly guide on how to go about get the method or advise on ways around using raw SQL.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52352636/pass-current-transaction-to-dbcommand/52352739#52352739

Answer (score 0):

You can use this generic method

```
public Task<List<TEntity>> ExecuteSqlCommand<TEntity>(string command, params object[] parameters)
        where TEntity : class
    {
        IQueryable<TEntity> q = null;

        using (var db = new YourDataContext(new DbContextOptions<YourDataContext>()))
        {

            if (parameters != null)
                q = db.Query<TEntity>().FromSql(command, parameters);

            else
                q = db.Query<TEntity>().FromSql(command);

            return Task.FromResult(q.ToList());
        }
    }
```

Bear in mind that `TEntity` is your output model class which should be defined first

Comment: This will not work as I am constructing the queries based on user selections

Comment: why not? you just need to make your query based on user inputs and place it as your `command`. you can also make a dynamic connection string

Answer (score 0):

I had to use the good old SqlClient.

> ```
> var connectionString = _configuration.GetConnectionString("ConnectionString");
>         List<string> queryColumns = null;   
>         DataTable dataRetrieved = new DataTable();
>         using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
>         {
>             con.Open();
> ```

```
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql ,con);
            SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            queryColumns = Enumerable.Range(0,reader.FieldCount).Select(reader.GetName).ToList();

            dataRetrieved.Load(reader); 
        }
```