# C# NetCore Transaction null

Tags: c#, .net-core, transactionscope, .net-6.0

I have many classes all associated to a specific table. On a higher level i have parent transactions that call various methods so the child methods must be able to work inside a transient transaction and often it is not known beforehand if a method at some stage will be part of a transaction or not since we try to keep them generic.

Then in some cases we need Dapper queries e.g. to turn identity on / off . I understood that Dapper requires passing a Transaction as parameter otherwise it will not be enlisted in the transaction (turns out i was wrong see below).

The DbContext(Pooling) is set per "component/dll" so since a connection is only enlisted when it its opened inside a transaction a scope is used of context to ensure it is opened for this transaction. Furthmore that helps when calling these same methods from e.g. HealthChecks who otherwise will complain about too many open connections when many of them call the same connections opened by services. Have this scope in methods helps also with calling these methods in parallel work so that they are more nicely run in parallel threads.

In other words in this way these methods can be called from these parents which can be parallel job parents or singletons requiring a service scope or parent transactions that require a transients hierarchy.

The problem was: For some reason transaction in the following transaction is always null.

```
try {
using TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required,
            System.TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10), TransactionScopeAsyncFlowOption.Enabled);

using Context localcontext = new Context(new DbContextOptionsBuilder<Context>()
                .UseSqlServer(_options.ConnectionString).Options);
// just for safety:
localcontext.Database.GetDbConnection().Open(); 

 // the following line is only for dapper input:
IDbContextTransaction transaction = localcontext.Database.CurrentTransaction;

await localcontext.Database.GetDbConnection()
  .ExecuteAsync("SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[Whatever] ON",
                null, (System.Data.IDbTransaction)transaction);
}
```

(which i took from here: [Pass current transaction to DbCommand](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52352636/pass-current-transaction-to-dbcommand) and here https://github.com/zzzprojects/Dapper.Transaction )

UPDATE / SOLUTION:

Ok. So... when using transaction scope the transaction parameter does not have to be passed to Dapper to ensure it enlists in the transaction. That was the clue.

Comment: Don't use a transaction scope to begin with. A DbContext is a Unit of Work. It's not a database connection or model. You don't need any of that code just to execute a single command. All you need is to create a new `SqlConnection` with that connection string, create a single SqlCommand with that SQL statement and execute it with `ExecuteNonQuery`. Or use Dapper and execute `connection.Execute(thatSQL)`. You don't need a transaction to execute a single command

Comment: You need a good connection string to make a connection to the database to get results.

Comment: @jdweng in this case almost all of the code is redundant.

Comment: This is not a single command but is in a chain of nested transactions spanning multiple classes so that the complete transaction rolls back over all methods. It archives specific main database tables to archive database tables based on filters.

Comment: @edelwater this code is wrong. Period. SQL Server doesn't have nested transactions anyway. All of the code you posted is redundant. *All* of the code you posted tries to do what `using var cn=new SqlConnection(_connectionString); cn.Execute(sql);` would also do. And if you're opening multiple connections inside a transaction scope, just to execute single commands, you're doing it wrong anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove this line

```
IDbContextTransaction transaction = localcontext.Database.CurrentTransaction;
```

If there's an active TrasnactionScope your SqlConnection will be automatically enlisted in it.  The whole point of TransactionScope is that your data access methods can be *completely free* of transaction handling.  Then in some outer business layer or controller method, the transaction is orchestrated.

The reason `CurrentTransaction` is null is that there are two different ways to handle transactions.  If you want the current System.Transactions.Transaction, you get it with `System.Transactions.Transaction.Current`.

Stepping back, there are 3 separate ways to manage transactions with SqlConnection.

1. **TSQL Transactions**: You can use TSQL API directly issuing `BEGIN TRAN`, `COMMIT TRAN`, etc.
2. **ADO.NET Transactions**: SqlConnection.BeginTrasaction, IDbTransaction , SqlTransaction, etc.  This is a wrapper over the TSQL API, and is a PITA because it *introduces* a useless requirement to pass the SqlTransaction to each SqlCommand that you want to enlist in the Transaction.  But enlisting TSQL commands in the current transaction is not optional, and never has been.  And that's a pain because methods that user SqlCommand may not know whether there is a transaction.  Dapper and EF both wrap this API in their transaction handling methods.
3. **System.Transactions Transactions**: Partly because of this [System.Transactions](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=1455) was introduced in .NET 2.0 as a new and unified way to handle transactions in .NET, and SqlClient added support for it.  The main innovation of System.Transactions was adding "ambient" transactions.  So code could be agnositc about whether there's a transaction and the right thing will just happen.  When opening a SqlConnection if there is a current Transaction, the SqlConnection will be enlisted in it, and the changes made using the SqlConnection will not be committed until the Transaction is committed.  And there is no need for your ADO.NET code to know about the Transaction.  Dapper and EF are both built on top of ADO.NET and SqlClient, so this all just works.

Comment: But I thought Dapper Queries REQUIRE passing the transaction in the query. And in this case because EF does not do identity insert off, i fire a dapper call.

Comment: See updated answer.

Comment: Yes, so i am relying on transient transaction. But I think for Dapper (the reason for https://github.com/zzzprojects/Dapper.Transaction existing) (i think) is that "transaction" needs to be passed to  Dapper query otherwise the dapper query is not involved in the transaction ?

Comment: That appears to be a Dapper extension that attaches to the ADO.NET transaction API, which is not used when using System.Transactions.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft it's not a Dapper extension at all, someone hijacked the Dapper name and started creating buggy "tutorials" and libraries without even talking to Marc Gravell. That "Dapper Tutorial" site you find every time you google for Dapper? That wasn't created by Marc Gravell and contains several bugs

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft in any case, the real Dapper's methods already accept a transaction parameter

Comment: But it's an IDbTransaction, not a System.Transactions.Transaction.  When using TransactionScope you can omit passing the transaction to Dapper, as SqlConnection  will enlist in the System.Transactions.Transaction.Current.

Comment: Ah... so when using a transation scope the 3rd parameter of transaction does NOT have to be passed to Dapper to ensure it enlists in the transaction. OK!

Comment: Yep.  Just make sure you don't have `enlist=false` in your connection string, and it should work.

Answer (score 1):

It's easier to explain what's wrong by showing what the code should be:

```
using(var connection=new SqlConnection(_connectionString))
{
    await connection.ExecuteAsync("SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[Whatever] ON");
}
```

Where `ExecuteAsync` comes from Dapper.

There's no reason to create a transaction, much less a transaction scope, to execute a single command.

There's no reason to create a DbContext just to open a connection to the database either, or to execute raw SQL commands. DbContext isn't a database connection, it's job is to Map Objects to Relational data. There are no objects involved here.

To execute multiple commands there's no reason to use multiple connections. Just execute the commands one after the other. If it's really necessary, use an explicit database transaction around those commands. Or create the connection inside a single transaction scope.

Let's say you have an array with those commands, eg something read from a script file :

```
string[] commands=new[]{...};
using(var connection=new SqlConnection(_connectionString))
{
    await connection.OpenAsync();

    using (var transaction = connection.BeginTransaction())
    {
        foreach(var sql in commands)
        {
            await connection.ExecuteAsync(sql,transaction:transaction);
        }
        transaction.Commit();
    }
}
```

Doing the same thing using a TransactionScope only requires opening the connection inside the transaction scope.

```
string[] commands=new[]{...};

using( var scope = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required,
            System.TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10), TransactionScopeAsyncFlowOption.Enabled)
using(var connection=new SqlConnection(_connectionString))
{
    await connection.OpenAsync();

    foreach(var sql in commands)
    {
        await connection.ExecuteAsync(sql);
    }
    scope.Complete();
}
```

Comment: well.. yes.. i understand i have a couple of thousand of regular classes using regular dbContext(pooling) over a gazillion project. But...  In some cases e.g. where we call parallel work and we have methods that are invoked in a parallel threads we use the using so that they actually run in that parallel context. In these same classes there are also methods that are part of TRANSIENT transactions like the above. And when these classes use Dapper then I think Dapper requires passing a IDBTransaction.

Comment: @edelwater don't involve the DbContext at all. In your code you are using the DbContext only to create a SqlConnection - 10 lines instead of 1. If your actual code is different, post that code

Comment: @edelwater besides, Dapper doesn't change how ADO.NET works at all. Neither does EF Core. A TransactionScope affects only the connections created inside it.

Comment: yes because the connection HAS to be opened within the transaction to be part of the transaction. And the dbcontext-pooling is used per component covering multiple services so if the dbcontext connection is called before this (and opening the first time opens it, its already open). So this ensures that. For dapper unfortunately this is not netcore: https://github.com/zzzprojects/Dapper.Transaction , therefore passing the transaction is needed.

Comment: @edelwater that's not the Dapper repository. That's someone that hijacked the `Dapper` name creating buggy "tutorials" to the point that people have to google for `DapperLib` to find the real repo. When you go to the real repo you'll find what I told you

Comment: @edelwater in fact, that repo you linked to does nothing more than what the real Dapper already does. Dapper's methods already accept a transaction parameter. That's why I used `transaction: ...` in my code. You'll have to ask whoever created that "Dapper Plus" without so much as a by-your-leave what the point of `Dapper.Transactions` is

Comment: ok so you are saying that to be able to pass the transaction parameter to a dapper query (otherwise it will not be part of the transaction) you have add another using scope with a new transaction to be able to grab the transaction but you can not get it from the current dbconnection without creating a new transaction scope inside the existing transaction scope.

Comment: @edelwater no. I'm saying that when you use a TransactionScope, the transaction is picked up by ADO.NET so you don't have to do anything. If you don't use a transactionscope, you have to pass the transaction. I have no idea what the non-Dapper library does, but it doesn't really matter, because that's how ADO.NET itself works. Dapper itself has no issue - the `transaction` parameter is optional after all.